# PHP & Mysql Syntax incorrect?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with this not running at all when the information is submitted, I believe that I have the syntax wrong.

```
 if ($_POST['note'] != $player->note_text) {
    $message = 'Admin '.$user.' has added the note ('.$_POST['note'].') to '.$player->name.'('.$pid.')';
    logIt($user, $message, $dbcon);
    $note = $_POST['note'];
    $note = '"'.$note.'"';
    $UpdateN = "INSERT INTO notes (uid, staff_name, name, alias, note_text, warning) VALUES ('$_POST[hidden]', '$user', '$player->name', '$player->aliases', '$note','$_POST[warn]')";
    $UpdateN2 = "INSERT INTO players WHERE `playerid` = $_POST[hidden] (warning) VALUES ('$_POST[warn]')";
    mysqli_query($dbcon, $UpdateN, $UpdateN2);
```

The new line I added which seems to have broken it is '$UpdateN2'.
I am not sure if the new line has broken the statement, since I am new to PHP and mysqli any pointers to forums or websites that I can learn and understand this in a more detailed way I would appreciate.

Edit: I have since moved from using mysqli to PDO, I strongly suggestion that anyone willing to start using MYSQL commands with PHP to have a look at this: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

I started reading this and testing things out, I find this much more easier but also it looks a lot cleaner and understandable when reading it back after a few days have passed.

Comment: There are numerous issues here. `mysqli_query` only takes 1 query.

Comment: Damn son, please use prepared statements if you want to enter user-supplied variables, you can never trust those users :P

Comment: Any basic sql tutorial would tell you that insert does not have a where clause. Mysqli_query can execute 1 query.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php   mysqli_query takes three arguments. The first is the connection, the (optional) third is the result mode.  Remove `,$UpdateN2` from the call to mysqli_query.   Syntax for that second insert statement is wrong, the WHERE clause is not allowed. And the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Please understand this is not my work so I am not in a postion to start changing loads of it. If someone could help me and add to this that would help me as well.

Comment: You need to go spend at least a full working day to understand this, helping you on this point is going to do you harm in the long run.

Comment: this code is dangerously bad, it will get you hacked. If you dont know what your doing, dont do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with the mysqli procedural style in the original, using prepared statements with bind placeholders, something like this:

```
   $UpdateN = 'INSERT INTO notes (uid, staff_name, name, alias, note_text, warning)'
            . ' VALUES ( ?, ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )';

   $UpdateN2 = 'UPDATE players SET warning = ? WHERE playerid = ? ';

   if( $sth = mysqli_prepare($dbcon,$UpdateN) ) {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'ssssss'
         ,$_POST['hidden']
         ,$user
         ,$player->name
         ,$player->aliases
         ,$_POST['note']
         ,$_POST['warn']
      );
      if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {
         // statement execution successful
      } else {
         printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_stmt_error($sth));
      }
   } else {
      printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_error($dbcon));
   }

   if( $sth2 = mysqli_prepare($dbcon,$UpdateN2) ) {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth2,'ss'
        ,$_POST['warn']
        ,$_POST['hidden']
      );
      if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth2) ) {
         // statement execution successful
      } else {
         printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_stmt_error($sth2));
      }
   } else {
      printf("Error: %s\n",mysqli_error($dbcon));
   }
```

Comment: I tried this out and this works great for me but I do reieve and error.

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[hidden], $user, $player->name, $player->aliases, $note,$_POST[warn])' at line 1`

Comment: @ConnorNee: I made a few tweaks after I posted. (I had a missing paren, a wrong variable name `$stsh2`.) I should have added `mysqli_stmt_close` calls too.  Is it a PHP error, or a MySQL error? If it's one of the print("Error:" messages, consider adding a literal in the message text to discriminate which line in the code is emitting it, `printf("staff#01 prepare Error:`, `printf("staff#02 execute Error:`, etc. If it's a MySQL error, then that should indicate the nature of the problem. I'd be emitting the values that were supplied for the bind variables.

Comment: @ConnerNee.  I suspect you neglected to replace the variables in the SQL text with bind placeholders **`?`** (question mark characters). Please review the example SQL text assigned to `$UpdateN`... note the `VALUES (?,?,?,`.

Comment: No, I got what you meant from using '?' so I changed them.

Comment: Found out what the error was refereing to `printf("Staff2: %s\n",mysqli_error($dbcon));`

Comment: So, its the call to `mysqli_prepare` that is throwing the error. In the code in this answer, there is no possible way that the string  "`[hidden], $user, $player->name`" will appear in the SQL text that is being passed to `mysqli_prepare`. (The code only does one assignment to `$UpdateN`, and it's a literal. We can easily verify that the string reported in the error message does not appear in the SQL text. As the next step in debugging, `printf` the contents of `$UpdateN` where that error is being emitted.

Comment: I do not understand the last part, are you telling me to do something or informing me?

Comment: The code in this answer is intended to *replace* the last three lines of code posted in the question. Starting with the assignment to `$UpdateN`. If the error message is being reported from the `printf`  when `mysqli_prepare` returns FALSE, then there must be some other line of code that's assigning a different value to `$UpdateN`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am greatdul that you have helped me with this and I have passed it on to the original author of the panel.

Comment: I think I just understood what you just said in an earlier comment, regarding the *bind placeholders*, the question mark characters. Those question mark characters in the SQL text **need to be** LITERAL question mark characters. Those are *bind placeholders* Exactly literal question mark characters, exactly like I had them in my code. Do *NOT* replace the question marks.

Comment: ah okay, I thought you meant I had to replace them.

Comment: I thought 'UPDATE' would add to the current value in a column rather than replace it.

Comment: The SQL `UPDATE` statement is intended to assign a value to a column of *existing* rows in table, to *replace* the value that is currently stored.  The `INSERT` statement creates a new row. It's not entirely clear what you are attempting to achieve, I am guessing that you are wanting to modify an existing row in the `players` table, identified by a particular value in the `playerId` column.  `SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerId = 666`. To modify that row, `UPDATE players SET warn = 'you been warned' WHERE playerid = 666`

Comment: I googled it and found that this worked `$UpdateN2 = 'UPDATE players SET warning = warning + ? WHERE playerid = ? ';`

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: In MySQL, the `+` is numeric addition operator. I can't see what the datatype of `warning` is. The `+` is appropriate if `warning` column is numeric datatype (INT,DECIMAL,FLOAT, etc.).  If that's a *character* data, and you are are wanting to append to the existing value, then you'd use the `CONCAT()` function.  `SET warning = CONCAT(warning,?)` Either way, be aware of the behavior with NULL values. Both `+` operation and `CONCAT` function will return NULL.  (Confusingly, SQL Server does use the `+` operator for string concatenation. When you are googling, be aware of *which* DBMS.

Comment: Thank you, learned some new things and I will look into a place where I can teach myself.

Comment: Good luck to you Connor. I wish you success in your endeavors. Yes, it's a steep hill, and there is no easy chairlift ride to the top. It has to be scaled step by step. And security is *not* an afterthought, to be applied after everything is working. Learn and practice good coding techniques. I'll recommend you bookmark the OWASP project  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet  Primary Defense 1 is *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I'd just make two separate calls to mysqli_query, one for each of your separate queries. PHP has historically been very wary of permitting multiple queries in a single function call, because of possible sql injection vulnerabilities.

On a related note, you need to sanitize your input. $_POST should never, ever, ever appear directly in a mysql query string, because your post data might -actually be something like ')"; DROP TABLE users;'.

Finally, you're using a WHERE clause on an insert. That's probably breaking your query. You should take a couple of days and research how and why that's breaking your query, and how and why to write proper sql queries. Doing so will add value to your company, because your company is less likely to suffer a catastrophic data breach, and it will add value to you, because you'll be a better SQL coder.

Edit: and in the time it took me to write this, three different people made each of those points. LOL.

Comment: This is just for a gaming community and allows us to manage in-game data linked to a player's character.

Comment: What this particular snippet is actually doing is allowing an admin to post a comment to a user. You actually want to do an UPDATE, not an INSERT, and the evidence suggests that if I help you, other than to direct you to read a SQL tutorial, you are only going to further damage your website database and security. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I understand, I am new and interested in this but since this is not my work I would have no clue what I need to learn to allow me to complete my needs.

Comment: If you are still stuck on this, here is some php documentation on injection vulnerabilities. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

If that looks like a heap of gibberish, go back to here first: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

BUT DON'T WRITE ANY CODE until you've read and understood the bit about sql injections.